# Steam authenthication for asp.net website

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, steam, steam-web-api

Can you talk me how I can make authorization throught Steam at my website on Asp.Net Web API C#? I found this only for php. Some code used for desktop, but nothing for web api. I have not any code. I want to make Steam OpenId authenthication with c#. It's Steam auth with php https://github.com/SmItH197/SteamAuthentication but I need this with C#. I found some code but this code for desktop app (as I know)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
var openid = new OpenIdRelyingParty();
var response = openid.GetResponse();

if (response != null)
{
    switch (response.Status)
    {
        case AuthenticationStatus.Authenticated:
            // do success
            var responseURI = response.ClaimedIdentifier.ToString();
            //"http://steamcommunity.com/openid/id/76561197969877387"
            // last part is steam user id
            break;

        case AuthenticationStatus.Canceled:
        case AuthenticationStatus.Failed:
            // do fail
            break;
    }
}
else
{
    using (OpenIdRelyingParty openidd = new OpenIdRelyingParty())
    {
        IAuthenticationRequest request = openidd.CreateRequest("http://steamcommunity.com/openid");
        request.RedirectToProvider();
    }
}
```

}

How I can use it for site?

Comment: Have you tried using the API in C#, do you have any code?

Comment: Can you show some of your code ? And which Steam authentication you mean ?

Comment: @Wurd I add some information

Comment: @Z3RP I add some information